# TypeError: source is not an object properties = Object.keys(source);

Tags: magento, prototypejs, enterprise

I am getting this error in prototype.js in console

`TypeError: source is not an object properties = Object.keys(source);`

What could be causing this issue?
Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well from the error it looks like the variable `source` is not an object and you would not be able to get the keys of that object. We would need more context to be of any more help

Comment: anyone found solution ???